# Understanding the attoparsec parser monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I am currently trying to study the source code of the `attoparsec` library and now I am stuck at the monad definition of the `Parser`. See [here.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.12.1.2/docs/src/Data-Attoparsec-Internal-Types.html#Parser)

```
instance Monad (Parser i) where

   fail err = Parser $ \t pos more lose _succ -> lose t pos more [] msg
      where msg = "Failed reading: " ++ err

    return v = Parser $ \t pos more _lose succ -> succ t pos more v

    m >>= k = Parser $ \t !pos more lose succ ->
        let succ' t' !pos' more' a = runParser (k a) t' pos' more' lose succ
        in runParser m t pos more lose succ'
```

Escpecially I am having trouble to wrap my head around the definition of the `(>>=)`operator.
For example in the expresson `let succ' t' !pos' more' a = runParser (k a) t' pos' more' lose succ`: Where are the parameters `pos'` and `t'` are coming from??

Maybe I am currently too confused and can't see the obvious, so I would appreciate if someone could explain the monad-definition of the `Parser` type to help me understand it better...

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is defining a function `succ'`:

```
succ' :: Success i (State i) a r
succ' t' !pos' more' a = runParser (k a) t' pos' more' lose succ

-- type Success i t a r = t -> Pos -> More -> a -> IResult i r
-- t' :: t
-- pos' :: Pos
-- more' :: More
-- a :: a
-- runParser (k a) t' pos' more' lose succ :: IResult i r
```

Nothing special going on, it's just a local function definition.  This function is then passed to `runParser` as its last argument.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so blind, I see it now